# how to share vals between build.sbt and assembly.sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I'm using two files for my build: build.sbt and assembly.sbt (for building fat jars using sbt-assembly plugin).  I have some vals defined in build.sbt.  Let's just say I'm doing some custom tasks that depend on them.  However, I noticed that vals defined in build.sbt are not visible in assembly.sbt.  So I end up duplicating code in those two files.  How do I configure it such that assembly.sbt can see the vals in build.sbt?

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't supported by .sbt syntax currently.

You can place shared vals in  a `project/lib.scala` file though

Comment: Hi jsuereth!  How does that work?  Once I create the lib.scala, do I import that into build.sbt and assembly.sby?

Comment: I'll create a real answer.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, val in `*.sbt` files are meant to be namespace separated.   We've debated the merits of having a global namespace or not, but in the end keeping them separate makes things a lot more consistent.

The "sbt" way to share vals and settings *between* build.sbt is to either:

- Create a plugin which does so.
- Create a "library" in the `project/` directory which does so.

For option #2, you can do the following:

**project/lib.scala**

```
package mylib

object MyStuff {
   val foo = "hi"
}
```

**build.sbt**

```
import mylib.MyStuff

// Just reference .scala code from the project/ directory.
name := MyStuff.foo
```

Hope that helps!